# How to install telnet in Docker for Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-machine, blockchain

When I run telnet command in Docker it does not run.

[image]

Could you please tell me how to install telnet in Docker for Windows?

Comment: I have rub telnet command and it says command not found , i am new in this i dont know how to install telnet in it

Comment: How are you trying to use telnet in your container?

Comment: that it what i am asking , i am trying to run telnet in my docker container , how to do that ,

Comment: pls bear with me i am complete novice in docker

Comment: Okay, but I think you should look for a Beginner's Guide for Docker and then ask your questions :D `docker run -it ubuntu bash` gives you a shell in ubuntu. There you can use the normal shell commands, e.g. `apt-get update && apt-get install xinetd telnetd` [see here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/668725/how-can-the-telnet-service-on-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts-be-enabled). After this you have telnet installed and can use it with `telnet <ip>`. But you have no understanding what Docker is, so you should learn this first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122487/discussion-between-n2o-and-monis).

Comment: There is a docker image on docker hub for telnet: https://hub.docker.com/r/mikesplain/telnet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a docker image for it:

```
docker run mikesplain/telnet <host> <port>
```

Comment: the image is based on alpine!

Answer (score 7):

Old question I know but you can install telnet on docker for windows with the following in your dockerfile

```
  RUN powershell -Command Add-WindowsFeature "telnet-client"
```

Comment: After adding the line I got an error: `hcs::CreateComputeSystem <some hash>: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.`

Comment: That is because the RUN dockerfile command needs start the container to exec the command inside. The given machine where the docker build was executed had missing features required for starting a container.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to telnet **into your container** to gain access to it, that isn't how you would want to connect. Docker provides that functionality.

Connect into a running container - [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/):

```
docker exec -it <container name> bash
$ root@665b4a1e17b6:/#
```

Start a container from image, and connect to it - [Docs](http://docker%20run%20-t%20-i%20--rm%20%3CimageName%3E%20bash):

```
docker run -it <image name> bash
$ root@665b4a1e17b6:/#
```

Note: If it is an Alpine based image, it may not have Bash installed. In that case using `sh` instead of `bash` in your commands should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Kubernetes, you could install `telnet` in k8s by running:

```
apk update
apk add busybox-extras
telnet 10.0.180.37 11211
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command will work if you want to install Telnet client in a running Windows Docker container. Just run this command in your container's terminal:

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
```