# How to install telnet client on windows nano server container?

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-for-windows

I need to test network access from a windows container, using the telnet client.
The only image i found for this is microsoft nano server, that does not come with telnet client.
I try to add it but seams the installer is not part of nano server image either.

How can i install it?

For clarity, here the steps i try:

```
docker run -it microsoft/dotnet:nanoserver powershell

// gives the error: Add-WindowsFeature : The term 'Add-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the     name of a cmdlet, function, script file,or operable program.
PS> powershell -Command Add-WindowsFeature "telnet-client"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install telnet in Docker for Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286441/how-to-install-telnet-in-docker-for-windows-10)

Comment: Nano server image is a specific image to run on windows type container. That post does not specify if wants a linux or windows container type, so answers do not apply.